# Promise is not executing succesfully within a recursively called parent function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, asynchronous, mongoose

I have the function `attemptSearch()` which is first ivoked and then it is supposed to call itself recursively until a certain condition is met. The code is only partially working right now.  The second `console.log()` is being called with each iteration, but the `console.log()` within the function `searchForPostcodes()` is only called once, during the initial invocation of `attemptSearch()`, which would suggest none of `searchForPostcodes()` code is being executed in the following iterations. Not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here.

*Just for added context, I have confirmed that the `Postcode.find` method is functioning fine in isolation. It is a method that belongs to mongoDB->Mongoose Modal*

```
let latMin = lat - 0.0005;
let latMax = lat + 0.0005;
let longMin = long - 0.0005;
let longMax = long + 0.0005;

const searchForPostcodes = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  console.log('test')
  Postcode.find({
    lat: {
      $gte: latMin,
      $lte: latMax
    },
    long: {
      $gte: longMin,
      $lte: longMax
    }
  }, (err, postcodes) => {
    if (err) {
      reject(err);
    } else {
      resolve(postcodes);
    }
  });
});
let searchAttempts = 0;

function attemptSearch() {
  latMin = latMin - 0.0005;
  latMax = latMax + 0.0005;
  longMin = longMin - 0.0005;
  longMax = longMax + 0.0005;

  searchForPostcodes
    .then(postcodes => {
      if (postcodes.length > 0) {
        res.json(postcodes);
      } else {
        if (searchAttempts < 100) {
          console.log(searchAttempts, latMin);
          searchAttempts++;
          attemptSearch();
        } else {
          res.status(400).send('No postcodes found');
        }
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(400).send(err);
    });
}
attemptSearch();
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are multiple problems here.   First off, inside of `attemptSearch()`, you must `return` the promise inside so you chain them all together.  Then, your additional calls to `attemptSearch()` don't actually do anything new with `searchForPostcodes` because that's a static promise, not a newly generated one.  You don't call your database again, you're just using the previous promise.

So, I implemented the following changes:

1. Changed searchForPostcodes into a function that can be executed each time through the recursion.
2. Switched to use the native promises in your database.
3. Add `return` to `return SearchForPostcodes().then().catch()` so it's linked into the same promise chain.
4. Add `return` to `return attemptSearch()` so the recursive call is linked into the same promise chain.

Here's the modified code:

```
let latMin = lat - 0.0005;
let latMax = lat + 0.0005;
let longMin = long - 0.0005;
let longMax = long + 0.0005;

const searchForPostcodes = function() {
    return Postcode.find({
        lat: {
            $gte: latMin,
            $lte: latMax
        },
        long: {
            $gte: longMin,
            $lte: longMax
        }
    });
}

let searchAttempts = 0;

function attemptSearch() {
    latMin = latMin - 0.0005;
    latMax = latMax + 0.0005;
    longMin = longMin - 0.0005;
    longMax = longMax + 0.0005;

    return searchForPostcodes().then(postcodes => {
        if (postcodes.length > 0) {
            res.json(postcodes);
        } else {
            if (searchAttempts < 100) {
                console.log(searchAttempts, latMin);
                searchAttempts++;
                return attemptSearch();
            } else {
                res.status(400).send('No postcodes found');
            }
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(400).send(err);
    });
}
attemptSearch();
```

FYI, if this were my code, I would pass the `latXX` variables to `searchForPostcodes()` as function arguments rather than make them higher scoped variables.